# Get main window hwnd from process ID

Tags: c++, winapi

I read an example of this in this thread

[C++: Best way to get Window Handle of the only window from a process by process id, process handle and title name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162359/c-best-way-to-get-window-handle-of-the-only-window-from-a-process-by-process)

However it gives me an error I do not understand.

```
    1   IntelliSense: argument of type "BOOL (__stdcall CProcess::*)(HWND handle, LPARAM lParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "WNDENUMPROC"
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That's a pointer to a member function. You need to pass in a pointer to a standalone or class static procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get main window handle from process id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a non-static member function as a C language callback, because the member function has a hidden *this* argument.

In Windows you can use a static member function, but note that that is not a portable solution.

The most portable and safest is a namespace scope function.

Comment: Portability is very likely not a design goal, when passing a function pointer to [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) (a Windows API call).

Comment: @IInspectable: You're right: no Windows compilers I know (admittedly very few now, but still) are fuzzy about this. I mentioned portability with regard to what conventions one adopts. It's a good idea to write system-portable code also for pure Windows programs, when that's possible, because the conventions and coding guidelines etc. transfer more easily, and because others may find it easier to understand / more familiar.