# open and close an external program from Delphi

Tags: delphi, shellexecuteex

in my app (Delphi XE10) i want to open a file (RTF) with user's default editor (MSword or OpenOffice writter or else) and be able to close this editor from my app.
I tried to use the code bellow but without success on closing the editor

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var hApp : Cardinal;
begin
    hApp := StartApp('open','temp.rtf','','',sw_normal);
    anotherForm.showmodal;
    KillProcess(hApp);
end;
```

where:

```
function StartApp(apchOperation, apchFileName, apchParameters, apchDirectory: PChar;awrdShowCmd: Word): Cardinal;
var
    lseiInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
    Result := 0;
    FillChar(lseiInfo, SizeOf(lseiInfo), Chr(0));
    lseiInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(lseiInfo);
    lseiInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    lseiInfo.lpVerb := apchOperation;
    lseiInfo.lpFile := apchFileName;
    lseiInfo.lpParameters := apchParameters;
    lseiInfo.lpDirectory := apchDirectory;
    lseiInfo.nShow := awrdShowCmd;
    if Boolean(ShellExecuteEx(@lseiInfo)) then
    Result := lseiInfo.hProcess;
end;

procedure   KillProcess(hProcess: Cardinal);
Var
  ovExitCode: LongWord;
begin
    try
        if hProcess <> 0 then begin
            GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, ovExitCode);
            if (ovExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE) or (ovExitCode <> WAIT_OBJECT_0) then
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, ovExitCode);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        end;
    except
    end;
end;
```

The editor opens but when it must close with KillProcess, ovExitCode is allways zero so TerminateProcess doesn't execute. I also try to execute TerminateProcess at any case but the editor (MSword in this case) doesn't close.

Can you help me please ?
thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't going to be possible in generality.

Comment: In GetExitCodeProcess's documentation you'll find information about finding out why it fails.

Comment: Also, your `try...except` is pointless.

Comment: I found out that this happens when is active another instance of MSword.

Comment: I found out that this happens when is active another instance of MSword. If there is only one (my app's) then works ok. The only problem is that when MSword reopens suggests recovery of the previous document. It seems that TerminateProcess does an abnormal termination. Is there a solution, please ?

Comment: Your entire approach is doomed to fail. Find a different solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest dropping the `KillProcess` approach and use `SendMessage()` with WM_CLOSE instead. This way your application will exit in a "normal" way. You can get the window handle from the process handle, it is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20163705/3936440

Comment: Yes, you are right but the code you suggest is in C and i can't translate to Delphi (i tried but without success).

Comment: @JimPapas Have you already researched how to use `SendMessage()` in Delphi? There are plenty of articles around the web describing this.